# How do I strip the search params from an URL before sending it over the network in a Service Worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I am building an application that will utilize ServiceWorker and Indexed DB to cache data and allow users to work offline. The site uses two pages: index.html and activity.html. The home page will show a list of activities. When one of these activities is selected, it redirects to activity.html and passes the selected activity as a URL parameter. The page is loaded with data pulled from Indexed DB for that particular activity.

The idea is that the user logs in to the home page in the morning, then can go offline and access each of their activities without internet connection. This works if the user opens each activity while online, then goes offline. However, if they only access the home page, then go offline, then click on an activity, they get this error:

> Failed to load
> ‘https://[site]/activity.html?activityid=35956087’.
> A ServiceWorker passed a promise to FetchEvent.respondWith() that
> rejected with ‘TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch
> resource.’.

I am guessing I'm not caching something correctly, but I can't figure out why. This is the serviceworker.js:

```
var urlsToCache = [
    '/[webapp]/activity.html', //Web app title removed for posting online
    '/[webapp]/index.html',
    ...
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  // Perform install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
       console.log('Service Workers opened cache');
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
      })
  );
});


self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(function(){
    
  }
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
        // Cache hit - return response
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }

        return fetch(event.request).then(
          function(response) {
            // Check if we received a valid response
            if(!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
              return response;
            }

            // Copied from another source:
        // IMPORTANT: Clone the response. A response is a stream
            // and because we want the browser to consume the response
            // as well as the cache consuming the response, we need
            // to clone it so we have two streams.
            var responseToCache = response.clone();

            caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
              .then(function(cache) {
                cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
              });

            return response;
          }
        );
      })
    );
});
```

EDIT: I have determined that the issue is caused by the URL parameter (which, IMO, is entirely ridiculous). What's the proper way to strip the URL parameters from the request?

Comment: Can you share the site url? Above sw code should work.

Comment: Why do you think it’s ridiculous? The service worker should cache a request including its query parameters, right? A server can render a page entirely different based on query parameters.

Comment: @VimalPatel, the URL is in the error message, just with the actual domain redacted: https://[site]/activity.html?activityid=35956087

Comment: @Phortuin, Service Workers are intended to allow a website to mimic a native application by forgoing a connection to a server. If you rely on the server to render the page, then Service Workers are essentially useless. You (the user) could just access the browser cache instead. The true benefit of Service Workers comes from caching the source page and scripts and handling the rendering (or parameters) on the front end so that it will work while offline. It's overcomplicated and potentially impossible to cache every URL/parameter combination.

Comment: I agree that it's impossible to cache very URL/parameter combination, but a service worker should (if not otherwise instructed) cache every unique request. If it wouldn't, a million other developers would complain that it's "entirely ridiculous" that the service worker ignores query parameters. Anway, the { ignoreSearch } solution is exactly what we all needed :)

Comment: That I will agree to - then we can at least easily control what happens without having the need to clone the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Guerric P's option of cloning the response will likely work, the simplest option to ignore the URL parameters (as I later discovered and successfully implemented) is to use the "ignoreSearch" parameter of the cache.match() function.

Replace this:

```
  event.respondWith(caches.match(event.request)
```

With this:

```
event.respondWith(caches.match(event.request, {'ignoreSearch' : true})
```

Per the documentation:

> ignoreSearch: A Boolean that specifies whether to ignore the query
> string in the URL.  For example, if set to true the ?value=bar part of
> http://example.com/?value=bar would be ignored when performing a match. It
> defaults to false.

Full documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/match

If you need to actually change the request in any way, such as modifying the URL parameters instead of ignoring them in the fetch request, you will need to use Guerric P's option of cloning the request.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the URL of a [`Request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request), you have no other choice than creating a new one by extracting properties from the current one, because of these three reasons:

- The [`Request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request) object is immutable by design
- The [`Request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request) constructor takes a [`Request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request) as first parameter but takes no URL as second parameter
- The [`Request.clone()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/clone) method just creates an exact copy of the [`Request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request) and takes no parameter

Here is a possible generic implementation of a `stripParameters` function that clones a [`Request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request) while stripping parameters from the URL and preserving the other properties (like `method`, `headers` and others):

```js
const req = new Request("https://www.stackoverflow.com/path?param=foo", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "Authorization": "token" }
});

function stripParameters(request) {
  const keys = Object.entries(
    Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Request.prototype)
  )
    .filter(([, value]) => !value.writable)
    .map(([key]) => key);
  const extractedProperties = keys.reduce(
    (acc, cur) => ({ ...acc, [cur]: request[cur] }),
    {}
  );
  const url = new URL(extractedProperties.url);
  const strippedUrl = url.href.replace(url.search, "");
  return new Request(strippedUrl, extractedProperties);
}

console.log(stripParameters(req));
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains why I couldn't just edit the URL directly... I did find somewhere else online that you can now use the "ignoreSearch" parameter on the respondWith, which sounds like it will do the same thing, but doesn't require more code. Is there any downside to this? Ex: event.respondWith(caches.match(event.request, {'ignoreSearch' : true}).then(function(response){...}))

Comment: This parameter is not a parameter of `event.respondWith`, it's a parameter of `cache.match`. It's just a more lax matching mode to retrieve a request from the cache. From what I understand you don't need this, you need to remove the search params before sending the request on the network.

Comment: I did more reading on cache.match() after finding out that you can pass parameters. While the above solution of cloning the request will likely work, simply using 'ignoreSearch' : true will do the exact same thing. I was able to get this to work. See the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/match